# New router - lag spikes

Tags: router, ping, lag

I've recently bought a new router (actually not me but my family, and I consider their choice as bad).
Now I have some lag spikes all the time when I use internet. It's mostly seen in games but also when I'm downloading something or travelling around the internet. Running ping test shows that its not only my imagination. I don't have any knowledge about that stuff and I don't know where should I look for reason of this situation.

Router I bought is Dlink Dir-300.
Should I configure something for this router (right now all defaults).
My internet provider says that its not their fault, but its a bad company which I will change when I will have opportunity. Can I check somehow is it my router or they cause this problems?

Comment: I would suggest running a ping -t www.google.com AND a ping -t <router's ip> side by side. If the lag spikes occur on both then it is your router. If it only occurs on google, it is possibly the ISP.

Comment: @xxl3ww Done that, and lags only occur on google, router in that time is OK! So can I be now 100% sure that its my provider's fault?

Comment: I would not completely rule out the router. When you are pinging both the router and google, what is the reply from the router? It should be <1ms. Another test to see if it is the ISP or your router is to unplug the router and run the ping tests to google. If it lags like this, then it must be the ISP or the ISP's equipment

Comment: @xxl3ww Plugged my laptop directly "to the wall" and still the same. So its my provider fault, but they say its not... Lets suppose that they don't lie. Maybe its my NICs (plural form cause tested on 2 computers). I've tried with auto ip and provided ip by hand - same results. What else can I try and is there any sense doing it?

Comment: If I were you, I would request the ISP send a tech out and make sure he connects his equipment and tests the issue. If he says the high ping is normal, then I would suggest switching carriers. When I first signed with Comcast, it took many tech calls before one of them decided to fix the problem. The other techs said "ohh, that is normal, it will clear up on its own". My problem was related to splitters. He replaced all the coaxial splitters and I haven't had any issues since.